# Titanium studio trying to save image from blob

Tags: javascript, post, titanium, blob

I am using titanium studio and i am trying to save am image from a POST request.

```
 function buyImage(s){


var userName = Ti.App.Properties.getString('username');
    var email = Ti.App.Properties.getString('email');
    var encKey = Ti.App.Properties.getString('key');



var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

    // function called when the response data is available
    onload : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Key Text: " + this.responseData);


        Titanium.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(this.responseData,{
    success: function(e) {
        Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title:'Photo Gallery',
            message:'Check your photo gallery for you image'
        }).show();      
    },
    error: function(e) {
        Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title:'Error saving',
            message:e.error
        }).show();  
    }


});


        Titanium.UI.createAlertDialog({title:'Photo Gallery',message:'Photo saved to gallery'}).show();     

    },
    onerror : function(e) {
        Ti.API.info(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout : 5000 // in milliseconds
});
// Prepare the connection.
client.open("POST", "http://somesite/create/save?userName="+userName+"&encryptionKey="+encKey+"&email="+email+"&recordId="+s);
// Send the request.        
client.send();
```

The image says it saves ok and it says the responce data is a TiBlob but the image does not seem to save at all. When the same post is done in a post event in a browser you are prompted to download the image.

any ideas?

Comment: First of all, this would only work on iPhones (as you didn't mention a platform). And second: what type of image do you want to store?